# saving issues osx 10.8 adobe photoshop on server smb

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx, server-message-block, windows-sbs, adobe

we get several saving issues while saving files in Adobe applications CS 6 (especially in Photoshop) on a Windows Server 2003 Share connected via SMB.
Unfortunately the problems aren't able to be reproduced.
Errors we get: "File already exists", "No permission" and so on.
But when saving the file to the desktop and then drag the file on the server everything works as expected, the file will be overridden with no issues.

Has anyone an idea what we can do?

Our systems: OS X 10.8, Adobe CS 6, Windows SBS 2003 (AFP is not installed)

Oliver

Comment: What troubleshooting have you tried so far?

Comment: Except googleing nothing. But i have nothing suitable found.
I have looked at the file permissions but they are all ok.

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4624558 says there might be a known MacOS bug - We are troubled by such problems now since 2007 and Mac OS 10.5. The SMB filesharing handling of Mac OS is more than poor and badly documented. If Apple would be more open about this that would be a start. Hope we'll see some links here.